# What's the most secure way of storing user data client side with javascript?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, local-storage

So I've created a `socket.io` chat app and I'm needing to store the following details on the browser (so I can easily access them when they revisit the site):

1. User auth token ( A user is validated with this token, it's unique to the user)
2. Chat Id ( This is there so when the user wants to send a message I can simply append the chat Id to the function ) - So basically the user will send a message to this chatId

What I've done so far is use html 5's `localstorage`. From what I've heard it's not secure at all and a lot of browsers do not support this!

Any ideas? I was thinking maybe I just store the `userAuthToken` in a cookie and whenever they visit the site, it simply queries the server which returns the `chatId's` that the user is apart of. Or maybe some sort of `node` session store? I'm using `express, node, and socket.io`

Comment: The only way to evaluate the "most secure" solution is to enumerate your threat model. Who do you want to protect the data from? The users? Another website? A malicious executable?

Comment: *"and a lot of browsers do not support this"* Only if you count decade old ones or hopelessly useless ones.

Comment: Although it sounds like in your use case, you should store data in session cookie. See this page for best practices with express cookies: http://expressjs.com/advanced/best-practice-security.html

Comment: Well I don't want other users being able to access there chats by grabbing there `authKey`, so that's why I didn't really want to use `localStorage`. Also `localStorage` doesn't seem to work on phone browsers (tried it on safari). I'll check out the express js sessions, but won't that mean when the user leaves the browser, there will be no express sesssion anymore? Meaning that they'll have to log in again? @TennysonH

Comment: @James111 You can set the session cookie to expire after x hours, or days. That way they'll always have the cookie for that amount of time, unless they clear their cookies. Cookies are how most sites store "authentication."

Comment: How does it work because I'm not using a `rest` api, I'm using `socket.io` to transfer data to and from the server! @TennysonH

Comment: @James111 you should initiate the authentication with a login system, store a session cookie, and then when opening a websocket, send the stored authentication key and verify the validity on the server. Then you know the data coming on the websocket is authenticated.